# String companion object in scala

Tags: scala, scala-implicits

Given a type which has a "converter", I would like to have automatic conversion on method call using this type's companion object. That is, given the following definition,

```
case class Converted(name: String)

trait Converter[A] {
  def perform: Converted
}

implicit val StringConverter = new Converter[String] {
  def perform = Converted("String")
}
```

make the following code to work:

```
implicit def toConverter(a: String.type): Converted = 
  implicitly[Converter[String]].perform // Error: `Found String.type, required AnyRef`

def f(needsConverted: Converted) = ???

f(String) // <- That's what I would like to be able to write.
```

But this fails and both attempts for conversion fail. Note that I cannot change `f` because it is provided by a third-party library and there are many of them.

1. Can I make `f(String)` compile using implicits?

---

If not possible for Strings, what about classes which do have a companion object, can I do this generically like:

```
object TheClass

case class TheClass()

implicit val TheClassConverter = new Converter[TheClass] {
  def perform = Converted("TheClass")
}

implicit def toConverter[A: Converter](a: A.type): Converted =
  implicitly[Converter[A]].perform // Error: `Not found value A`

implicit def toConverter(a: TheClass.type): Converted = 
  implicitly[Converter[TheClass]].perform // This works but is not generic

f(TheClass) // This works.
```

2. Can I make the first `toConverter` to compile ?

Comment: I suppose there's a good reason, but why don't you do `implicit val TheClassConverter: Converter[TheClass.type] = ???` ?

Comment: Thanks that answers my second question. Can I now write something for `String`?

Comment: ok I found for `String`. I just need to define an `object String`... If you provide your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: If your `Converter[A]` really doesn't use `A` anywhere in its body, why does it have the type parameter? If it does, having a `Converter[MyClass.type]` when you need a `Converter[MyClass]` doesn't help.

Comment: Please note that the above question had a simplified example to reproduce the problem with implicits, but don't worry in my case I do use the type parameter `A` in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining an implicit instance for the type `MyClass` you can define an implicit instance for the companion type `MyClass.type`.

```
implicit val TheClassConverter: Converter[MyClass.type] = new Converted[MyClass.type] {
  def perform = Converted("MyClass")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I make f(String) compile using implicits?

No. You can define a value called `String`, of course, but it won't be related to the type `String`.

> ```
> implicit toConverter[A: Converter](a: A.type): Converted =
>     implicitly[Converter[A]].perform
> ```

`A` in `A.type` must be a *value*; it is not related to the type parameter `A`.

In fact, so far as Scala's type system is concerned, there is no relationship between a class/trait and its companion object. So you can't do what you want generically.

Of course, if you don't insist on using `()` instead of `[]`, it becomes trivial:

```
def f1[A: Converter] = f(implicitly[Converter[A]].perform)

f1[String]
f1[TheClass]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what are you trying to accomplish, but following works for me

```
case class Converted(name: String)

trait Converter[A] {
  def perform: Converted
}

implicit def toConverted(name: String) = Converted("String")
implicit def toIntConverted(int: Int) = Converted("Int")

def f(needsConverted: Converted): String = needsConverted.name

f("some")
f(5)
```

Comment: No, I'm really looking to be able to pass the *type* as an input to `f`, not a value of the `type`.  For now, I'm only able to write something like `f(TheClass)` the last example of my second question, and only if I have an implicit from `TheClass.type` to `Converter`. I would like to do the same for `String` and also generically if I have a type that can be converted to a `Converter`